# Apply styles to list randomly

Tags: html, css

I have three categories

- big
- normal
- small

I want to give  different styles to the three categories .for example : one of them will be bold , another one will be at big font size , the third one will be with a font family of "Tahoma"
each time user refresh the page , the 3 styles will be applied on the 3 categories in random order.

for example (big) category will be bold , when user refresh the page it will swap his style with another categories so it may be become at Tahoma font family or will has a big font size

How can i do something like that .

a good example for that is a categories or tags in blogs wich have different sizes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul>
  <li>big</li>
  <li>normal</li>
  <li>small</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something ?

Comment: You can't do this just with **html** and **css**. You need **javascript** or **jquery**. Btw put your **html** code too.

Comment: @syedQarib i know how to style each element but my problem is how to  randomly apply CSS .

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh , any recommended links ?

Comment: Not in mind right now but put your html code and I do the rest.

Comment: it is a simple HTML of unorderd list , any way i will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8n7f3yq7/1/

```
// Store the classes you want to apply in an array
var classes = ["big", "normal", "small"];

// Loop through every element and apply a random class
$("li").each(function(){
  index = Math.floor(Math.random()*(classes.length));
  $(this).addClass( classes[index] );
});
```

Comment: Excellent that's what i need to do ,but one more question:
Can it be done through CSS or CSS3 withut using Jquery ?

Comment: @Bassem unfortunately the answer is no.